# How do I prevent the user from clicking a button too often?

Tags: delphi

In a button-click event, I am sending a command to a server. I don't want the server to be flooded with requests, so I want to prevent the user from clicking the button too often.

I've thought about counting how many times the button is clicked, like this:

```
button.tag := button.tag + 1;
if button.Tag = 5 then
  exit;
```

But this will not help because I have to set the tag to 0 each time I need to detect the fast clicks, and this will also not help because it will detect the tag number every 5 clicks, whereas I just need to know if the button was clicked repeatedly.

How do I detect fast button clicks without using the button tag?

Comment: Many ways to do this. Is it sufficient to disable the button for a short period with a timer?

Comment: you mean while procedure is done i enable the button  ?

Comment: Yes that is a normal way to do it. Otherwise disable the button, start a timer and when the timer fires, enable the button. It all depends on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: its kinda  logical but this will prevent each time i need to use the button will not help

Comment: Then register number of clicks per seconds or any interval you seem fit. You really need to explain your goal, otherwise this is impossible to answer.

Comment: iam sending command using  a button from client to server i want prevent flood while sending like click  repeatedly is really fast to send commands.

Comment: Well then it sounds like you do need a timer. However, for your reasoning, I don't think you want to implement this on the UI layer.

Comment: If the user wants to click twice, what's the problem with that? Why are you stopping the user doing that?

Comment: if the user click twice his command will going flood the server imagine if there 100 users or more

Comment: So what if there are 100 users? You accepted an answer that suggests a timer based block. How do you choose the interval? What if there are 1000 users? How long to you need to wait? What if there are 100 users and each one clicks at the same time? You asked the question in a way that is likely to give answers that whilst addressing your question, won't help you solve the problem well. This is what happens when you decide ahead of time on the solution. You should have presented the problem rather than the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've correctly recognized that merely *counting* the clicks won't be sufficient. You need to account for the *time*, too. So use a *timer*.

When the button is clicked, disable the button and enable a timer. When the timer fires, re-enable the button.

```
procedure TExampleForm.SendButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Assert(SendButton = Sender);
  SendButton.Enabled := False;
  SendButtonTimer.Enabled := True;
  SendCommandToServer(...);
end;

procedure TExampleForm.SendButtonTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Assert(SendButtonTimer = Sender);
  SendButtonTimer.Enabled := False;
  SendButton.Enabled := True;
end;
```

Set the timer's `Interval` property to the number of *milliseconds* that you want the button to remain disabled.

There's no need to count the clicks in this scenario because the implicit limit is *one* click per timer interval.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to restrict how often to send commands from your client to the server, disable the button a short while after each click. This will give the user feedback that something is processing. I'm assuming there is no way the server can give feedback when it is ready.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1.Enabled := false;
  Timer1.Interval := 500;  // Pick a suitable interval 
  Timer1.Enabled := true;
  SendCommand(); // Make call to server
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
// Timer1 is disabled at startup
begin
  Button1.Enabled := true;
  Timer1.Enabled := false;
end;
```

**Note**: if you are trying to do some load balancing on the server, there must be a way for the clients to know how to restrict the calls. But this is all a backwards way of doing it, the server should be capable of handling this without any restrictions on the clients.

Answer (score 2):

You could just put some kind of timestamp into the Tag, and check whether enough time has elapsed.

Better yet, derive your own class, (TDontPressMeTooFastButton ;-), and you can do whatever you want, ie.:

- track both how much time elapsed since last click and how many "fast clicks" the user attempted
- you could make the button contain the timer component, not leaking this implementation detail into the form

Just about anything, in a much cleaner way than using the .Tag or global/form variables ...

Comment: if there a code to describe that  it will be more helpful .